# Scope of caught exception instance in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exception, scope

Since in Python variables are accessible outside of their loops and `try`-`except` blocks, I naively thought that this code snippet below would work fine because `e` would be accessible:

```
try:
    int('s')
except ValueError as e:
    pass
print(e)
```

In Python 2 (2.7 tested), it does work as I expected and the output is:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

However, in Python 3 I was surprised that the output is:

```
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I later found an answer as [PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/) explains that in Python 3 the caught name is removed at the end of the `except` suite to enable more efficient garbage collection. There is also recommended syntax if you wish to avoid this occurring:

> Situations where it is necessary to keep an exception instance around
>   past the end of the except suite can be easily translated like so
>
> ```
> try:
>     ...
> except E as N:
>     ...
> ...
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> try:
>     ...
> except E as N:
>     n = N
>     ...
> …
> ```
>
> This way, when N is deleted at the end of the block, n will persist
>   and can be used as normal.